# mvn versions:set doesn't update all pom.xml files

Tags: maven

We run `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=x.x.x` to update the version of our project.  For some projects it updates the version in all pom.xml files except one or two. What are some reasons that this command wouldn't update *all* files?

Comment: You should try to provide more inputs about the pom.xml files where the update is not performed. Else we can imagine many things.

Answer (score 0):

There are some reasons. The parent is not correctly set in the childs. The childs have different versions as the parent or the other childs. The child is only part of the aggregator based on some profiles.

So you can try with:

```
mvn version:set -DnewVersion=3.6.0 -DoldVersion=* -DgroupId=* -DartifactId=*
```

This is explained at https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/setaggregator.html.

For more advice we would need the pom files.